# Built a Vector2 class with easing functions, that can be unpacked

Tags: python, performance, vectors, easing

```
import math

def root(cls, nth):
    return cls.__root__(nth)


class Vector2(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.points = (x, y)
        self._index = 0

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.points[0]

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.points[1]

    # __str__ for customers, __repr__ for developers
    def __str__(self):
        return "(%s, %s)" % (self.x, self.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%r(%r)" % (self.__class__, self.__dict__)

    def __iter__(self):
        self.index = 0
        return iter((self.x, self.y))

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index >= len(self.points):
            self._index = 0
        result = self.points[self.index]
        self._index += 1
        return result

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.points[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.points[index] = value
        self.points = tuple(*self.points)

    # Right Hand Side == rhs
    def __add__(self, rhs):
        '''Add two Vector2 together'''
        return Vector2(self.x + rhs.x, self.y + rhs.y)

    def __sub__(self, rhs):
        '''Subtract one Vector2 from another'''
        return Vector2(self.x - rhs.x, self.y - rhs.y)

    def __neg__(self):
        '''Return Vector2 in reverse direction'''
        return Vector2(-self.x, -self.y)

    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        '''Multiply Vector2 by a scalar'''
        return Vector2(self.x * scalar, self.y * scalar)

    def __truediv__(self, scalar):
        '''Divide Vector2 by a scalar'''
        return Vector2(self.x / scalar, self.y / scalar)

    def __floordiv__(self, scalar):
        '''Divide Vector2 by a scalar'''
        return Vector2(self.x // scalar, self.y // scalar)

    def __mod__(self, scalar):
        '''Return floated modulo Vector by a scalar'''
        return Vector2(math.fmod(self.x, scalar), math.fmod(self.y, scalar))

    def __pow__(self, scalar):
        '''Return exponential pow of Vector, use root for nth roots'''
        return Vector2(pow(self.x, scalar), pow(self.y, scalar))
            
    def __root__(self, nth):
        '''Return the nth root of a vector'''
        return Vector2(pow(self.x, 1/nth), pow(self.y, 1/nth))

    def __round__(self):
        '''Round numbers to integer'''
        return Vector2(round(self.x), round(self.y))

    def __abs__(self):
        '''Return absolute values of Vector'''
        return Vector2(abs(self.x), abs(self.y))

    def __int__(self):
        '''Return integer values of Vector'''
        return Vector2(int(self.x), int(self.y))

    def __float__(self):
        '''Return floating point values of Vector'''
        return Vector2(float(self.x), float(self.y))

    def __complex__(self):
        '''Return absolute values of Vector'''
        return Vector2(complex(self.x), complex(self.y))

    def __ceil__(self):
        '''Return ceiling values of Vector'''
        return Vector2(math.ceil(self.x), math.ceil(self.y))

    def __floor__(self):
        '''Return floored values of Vector'''
        return Vector2(math.floor(self.x), math.floor(self.y))

    def __trunc__(self):
        '''Return absolute values of Vector'''
        return Vector2(math.trunc(self.x), math.trunc(self.y))

    def __bool__(self):
        '''If Vector is not (0.0, 0.0) return True'''
        if self.x != 0 and self.y != 0: return True
        else: return False

    def __lt__(self, rhs):
        '''Truthy statement of less than'''
        if self.x < rhs.x and self.y < rhs.y: return True
        else: return False

    def __le__(self, rhs):
        '''Truthy statement of less than or equal to'''
        if self.x <= rhs.x and self.y <= rhs.y: return True
        else: return False

    def __eq__(self, rhs):
        '''Truthy statement of equal to'''
        if self.x == rhs.x and self.y == rhs.y: return True
        else: return False

    def __ne__(self, rhs):
        '''Truthy statement of not equal to'''
        if self.x != rhs.x and self.y != rhs.y: return True
        else: return False

    def __gt__(self, rhs):
        '''Truthy statement of greater than'''
        if self.x > rhs.x and self.y > rhs.y: return True
        else: return False

    def __ge__(self, rhs):
        '''Truthy statement of less than or equal to'''
        if self.x >= rhs.x and self.y >= rhs.y: return True
        else: return False

    def __invert__(self):
        '''Return rounded Vector by inverted bitwise not'''
        x, y = round(self.x), round(self.y)
        return Vector2(~x, ~y)

    def __reversed__(self):
        '''Return Vector x,y swapped'''
        return Vector2(*tuple(reversed(self.points)))

    @staticmethod
    def from_points(P1, P2):
        return Vector2(P2[0] - P1[0], P2[1] - P1[1])

    @property
    def magnitude(self):
        return pow((self.x**2 + self.y**2), 1/2)

    def magnitude_squared(self):
        '''Return the squared magnitude (length) of the Vector2'''
        return self.x**2 + self.y**2

    @property
    def normalized(self):
        magnitude = self.magnitude
        self.points = (self.x / magnitude, self.y / magnitude)
        return Vector2(self.x, self.y)

    def lerp(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Linear Interpolation'''
        return self + (rhs - self) * scalar

    def easeInQuad(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Quadratic easing'''
        return self.lerp(rhs, scalar**2)

    def easeOutQuad(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Quadratic easing'''
        return self.lerp(rhs, 1 - (1 - scalar)**2)

    def easeInOutQuad(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Quadratic easing'''
        if scalar < 0.5:
            return self.easeInQuad(rhs, scalar * 2)
        else:
            return self.easeOutQuad(rhs, (scalar - 0.5) * 2)

    def easeInCubic(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Cubic easing'''
        return self.lerp(rhs, scalar**3)

    def easeOutCubic(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Cubic easing'''
        return self.lerp(rhs, 1 - (1 - scalar)**3)

    def easeInOutCubic(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Cubic easing'''
        if scalar < 0.5:
            return self.easeInCubic(rhs, scalar * 2)
        else:
            return self.easeOutCubic(rhs, (scalar - 0.5) * 2)

    def easeInQuart(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Quartic easing'''
        return self.lerp(rhs, scalar**4)

    def easeOutQuart(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Quartic easing'''
        return self.lerp(rhs, 1 - (1 - scalar)**4)

    def easeInOutQuart(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Quartic easing'''
        if scalar < 0.5:
            return self.easeInQuart(rhs, scalar * 2)
        else:
            return self.easeOutQuart(rhs, (scalar - 0.5) * 2)

    def easeOutQuint(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Quintic easing'''
        return self.lerp(rhs, 1 - (1 - scalar)**5)

    def easeInOutQuint(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Quintic easing'''
        if scalar < 0.5:
            return self.easeInQuint(rhs, scalar * 2)
        else:
            return self.easeOutQuint(rhs, (scalar - 0.5) * 2)

    def easeInSine(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Sinusoidal easing'''
        return self.lerp(rhs, 1 - math.cos(scalar * math.pi / 2))

    def easeOutSine(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Sinusoidal easing'''
        return self.lerp(rhs, math.sin(scalar * math.pi / 2))

    def easeInOutSine(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Sinusoidal easing'''
        return self.lerp(rhs, -0.5 * (math.cos(math.pi * scalar) - 1))

    def easeInExpo(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Exponential easing'''
        if scalar == 0:
            return self
        else:
            return self.lerp(rhs, 2**(10 * (scalar - 1)))

    def easeOutExpo(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Exponential easing'''
        if scalar == 1:
            return self
        else:
            return self.lerp(rhs, -2**(-10 * scalar) + 1)

    def easeInOutExpo(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Exponential easing'''
        if scalar == 0:
            return self
        elif scalar == 1:
            return self
        elif scalar < 0.5:
            return self.easeInExpo(rhs, scalar * 2)
        else:
            return self.easeOutExpo(rhs, (scalar - 0.5) * 2)

    def easeInCirc(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Circular easing'''
        return self.lerp(rhs, 1 - math.sqrt(1 - scalar**2))

    def easeOutCirc(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Circular easing'''
        return self.lerp(rhs, math.sqrt(1 - (1 - scalar)**2))

    def easeInOutCirc(self, rhs, scalar):
        '''Circular easing'''
        if scalar < 0.5:
            return self.easeInCirc(rhs, scalar * 2)
        else:
            return self.easeOutCirc(rhs, (scalar - 0.5) * 2)

    def easeInElastic(self, rhs, scalar, period=0.3):
        '''Elastic easing'''
        if scalar == 0:
            return self
        elif scalar == 1:
            return rhs
        s = period / 4
        scalar -= 1
        return self.lerp(rhs, -2**(10 * scalar) * math.sin((scalar - s) * (2 * math.pi) / period))

    def easeOutElastic(self, rhs, scalar, period=0.3):
        '''Elastic easing'''
        if scalar == 0:
            return self
        elif scalar == 1:
            return rhs
        s = period / 4
        return self.lerp(rhs, 2**(-10 * scalar) * math.sin((scalar - s) * (2 * math.pi) / period) + 1)

    def easeInOutElastic(self, rhs, scalar, period=0.3):
        '''Elastic easing'''
        if scalar == 0:
            return self
        elif scalar == 1:
            return rhs
        s = period / 4
        scalar *= 2
        if scalar < 1:
            return self.lerp(rhs, -0.5 * 2**(10 * (scalar - 1)) * math.sin((scalar - 1 - s) * (2 * math.pi) / period))
        else:
            return self.lerp(rhs, 2**(-10 * (scalar - 1)) * math.sin((scalar - 1 - s) * (2 * math.pi) / period) * 0.5 + 1)
```

Where I'm at:
Read a bunch of books from: No Starch Press and O'Reilly publishers concerning python. Read a bunch of code from github & here on stackoverflow. Watched (probably too much) youtube concerning gameDev in python, but channels such as: Clear Code, EuroPython Conference, ArjanCodes, mCoding, etc...

Hoping for:
Suggestions of better ways to handle and/or optimize this class or at least some good pointers of direction to take in research. For any and all help, I thank you ahead of time. Please note I am a hobbyist coder with a mentor, and there is a bunch of bits and pieces I'm still learning about when it comes to programming.

Comment: Do you have an intended application for this code? At what scale? For very small scale this will be fine. At scale it will be slow.

Comment: @Reinderien Working on learning about the basics of how 2d game engines operate, the mathematics behind it, and to write better/cleaner code for a try to make my own 2d game engine for a short goal. Long term goal is: Hoping to become good enough to be able to contribute to a project like Pygame, and then take it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks mostly fine to me, but I can see a few things that can be worked on.

## No need to inherit from `object`

Assuming you're working with Python 3 (and you should), all classes inherit from `object`, whether you explicitly do so or not.

## Naming conventions

[PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) recommends using `snake_case` for method names, which you actually use for some methods (like `magnitude_squared`) while others use `camelCase` (like `easeInQuad`). Even if you have a strong argument for preferring something other than `snake_case`, you should at least be consistent.

## Naming

I think `points` is a poor fit to hold the x- and y-coordinates of the vector. To my understanding, points would each be a pair of coordinates.

`coordinates` would probably be a better fit.

## YAGNI

*You Ain't Gonna Need It*, or probably not, at least. Unless you aim on making a full, general-purpose game engine, there is probably no need for all of these ease in/ease out methods, you'll probably end up using just a couple of these, at most.

## But maybe there are some things missing

If you intend to to any computation on your 2D vectors, chances are high you'll have to use dot- and cross-products, and you'll likely benefit from implementing these methods.

Same goes from converting to and from polar coordinates, scaling, or rotating a vector.

## About magic methods

Magic methods (those with names surrounded by double-underscores) are very useful, but to work as intended, they should be implemented properly. Implementing as many as you can is probably a good idea, but you shouldn't implement those that don't make much sense for your class.

### `root()` function and `__root__` method

I hesitated to include this in the "YAGNI" paragraph (you probably won't ever need to compute a vector with square root coordinates of the original vector), but it goes a bit further than that: you create a new convention. I can see what the appeal is, but it looks like it can create a lot of confusion.

Magic methods exist so that you can implement expected common behavior in your class. You'd expect to be able to add 2 vectors, and implementing `__add__` allows the user to seamlessly do that, which is nice. But nobody expects to be able to call `root` on any numeric type, so the pattern doesn't really work.

### `__pow__`

Does raising a vector to a power make sense? I'd argue that it doesn't. Even a simple case, such as `pow(v, 2)` isn't trivial, as you didn't define what the product of two vectors is. Even if you did, should I expect a cross-product or a dot-product? In any case, the result would be a scalar. But `pow(v, 3)` would be a vector, then. What about `pow(v, 2.5)`?

You decided to go with raising each of the coordinates to said power, but this doesn't represent any common mathematical operation.

You should remove this magic method IMO.

### Type conversion

The `int()`, `float()` and `complex()` functions, and their associated magic methods `__int__`, `__float__` and `__complex__` are intended to be used to for type conversion. However, you use them to convert the underlying data type of your vector, while returning a `Vector2`. This is bad, as I'd expect to be working with an `int` after calling `int(foo)`, whatever type `foo` was to begin with.

I suppose it doesn't make much sense to implement `__int__` and `__float__` in your case, but implementing `__complex__` can work:

```
    def __complex__(self):
        return complex(self.x, self.y)
```

### Inequality operators

There is no commonly-agreed-upon way to sort vectors. Is `(-20, -10)` really smaller than `(1, 1)`? But it's magnitude is greater! How can you compare `(-1, 1)` and `(1, -1)`? What if I want lexicographic ordering?

By implementing `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__gt__` and `__ge__`, you impose a comparison paradigm, which doesn't match usual vector comparison, and is confusing as it breaks the assumption that `not a > b` is equivalent to `a <= b`

### Absolute value

Almost, if not all, vector library I ever used use `abs(v)` or equivalent to return the magnitude of the vector. It makes sense from a mathematical point of view, where the magnitude of a vector and the absolute value of a complex number basically share their definition.

## About performance

There isn't much room for improvement performance-wise, as all methods of your class are pretty basic and don't have a lot of possible ways to implement them. I'd suspect packing the vector coordinates into a tuple add a bit of overhead and it might be somewhat faster to keep them as individual members, but that would require some verification.

Now, this is a pure Python class, so performance won't be great. Performance-critical Python code will usually be compiled C code with a Python wrapper, so if performance starts to be an issue, you'd need to look into that, but that is on a whole other level. Maybe you'll get to this some day. Otherwise, your best bet for performance is to use performance-optimized libraries as much as you can.

Comment: Thank you very much. You given me a good bit to look over, research, and work on towards improvement. One of my sub goals was to get as much as I can down in pure python before I start using outside modules, like for instance NumPy (seems to be a better to reconfigure this base idea). Would outside packages: NumPy, PIL, Pandas be a bit faster and/or better?